# Ruby time operations involving utc

Tags: ruby, time, utc

Why does this expression return false?

```
(Time.now - 10.hours).utc == Time.now.utc - 10.hours
```

Why accounts for the difference in the results? And which way is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they're not the same. Rubys `Time.now` tracks time to a fraction of a second, the output of `#to_s` just doesn't show that.

```
>> Time.now == Time.now
=> false
>> Time.now.to_i == Time.now.to_i  
=> true
>> Time.now.to_f == Time.now.to_f
=> false
```

Check out the documentation for the `Time` class [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html).

Comment: Of course if you run it enough times, `Time.now.to_i == Time.now.to_i` won't always be true.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the response. That makes sense. My initial reaction was that it had something to do with system elapsed time, but wanted to ask and make sure.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions are equivalent, but when called in sequence, will not return the same result.  Note:

```
Time.now == Time.now #=> false
Time.now - Time.now #=> Some really small negative number
```

If you call `Time.now` twice in a row, the 2nd one happens after the first, right?  Even if it's a ***very*** short amount of time after.

I wouldn't say either form is more right.  If you store `Time.now` and run the same comparison, you get the expected result.

```
t = Time.now
t.utc = 10.hours == (t - 10.hours).utc #=> true
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
(Time.now - 10.hours).utc.to_s == (Time.now.utc - 10.hours).to_s ==> true

(Time.now - 10.hours).utc - (Time.now.utc - 10.hours) ==> a small, non-zero
                                                          number. IE -1.3e-05
```

Note that a_time.to_s is the same as a_time.inspect and it only shows the time to the nearest second. But the internal resolution is much smaller than a sec.